# Increase size of toolbar and url bar in firefox?

Tags: firefox, interface, mozilla

I installed **Ubuntu 12.04**  and upgraded my Firefox.

However I would like to increase the size of the **"toolbar"** & **"urlbar"** like on Windows.
 *(The new firefox has big and nice interface to use)*.

[image]

How ca I do the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: You should install some themes from Firefox to get what you want or build your theme for firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to **edit/create** the **userChrome.css** inside of the **chrome** folder in your profile.

**1)** Close Firefox

**2)** Go to the firefox folder in you home. Open a Terminal and type:

- `cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/`

**3)** find out the name of your profile folder.
**eg:** the default profile name is **xxxxxxxx.default** *(where "x" are letters)*.
My case is **dfafal1w.default**

- `ls -l`

The result:

```
drwx------ 5 virtual virtual 4096 Oct  4 17:33 dfafal1w.default
```

**4)** Go to your profile folder.

- `cd xxxxxxxx.default`

where **"x"** are your profile letters.

**5)** find if your have a **chrome** folder and the **userChrome.css** file

- `ls -l chrome/userChrome.css`

**6)** if you have the file.. edit it with:

- `gedit chrome/userChrome.css`

Add the following lines to the end:

```
#urlbar {
min-height: 50px !important;
        }
```

*In this example I will set the minimum height of the urlbar to 50px. (Feel free to change it according to your needs)*

**7)** if you do not have the file and the folder... create them.

- `mkdir chrome`
- `cd chrome`

**8)** Create the **userChrome.css** and set the minimum height urlbar *(my case 50px)*.

```
cat > userChrome.css << EOF
#urlbar {
min-height: 50px !important;
        }
EOF
```

**9)** Open Firefox to see the changes...

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

**NOTE**:If you want the search bar in the same height of the urlbar... just add the following to the userChrome.css file.

```
#searchbar, .searchbar-textbox {
min-height: 50px !important;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Extremely interesting. How do I see  the list of supported fields that I can add in this .css file to customize firefox. Also there used to be chrome edit firefox addon but it isnt there anymore in the official addons.org anymore.

Comment: Glad to help. maybe these links could help you.In this article there is a list of Chrome element names and IDs http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_element_names_and_IDs .In this forum you can see css tweaks http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2057009